# Present databases on 2 SQL Servers like they are all on 1

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 SQL Servers, with several different databases on each. I want to present them as a single SQL Server showing all of the databases on either Sql Server.

We have yearly archive databases, so 1 database for each year. This year we decided to deploy a new SQL Server that will host newer years, so older yearly databases are on the old server, and future will be on new one.

I know I can link the servers, but I am not sure if I can do it in the transparent way so that no application has to change the query - so far I always had to use linked server explicitly in each query that uses it.

TLDR: I want to access databases on another SQL Server via main SQL Server so that app doesn't know or care about SQL Server details and don't need to have `if (Year > 2021) {then use this server } else {use that server}` type of logic and can behave like all databases live on the same server.

Comment: You can't `UNION` databases, you `UNION` `SELECT`statements. Having a seperate database for each year is just asking for problems; it doesn't scale and makes working with the data awful. You need to fix your design and have 1 database not many. Most likely what you want is table partitioning, which is available as standard in all fully supported versions of SQL Server

Comment: @Larnu, I am not talking about SQL Union :) You are not considering the problem I have, you invented a new one. Otherwise I agree with what you said.

Comment: Perhaps a better choice than "union" in your question would be wise then; `UNION` has a specific meaning in SQL. Though none of that changes my point. You don't want multiple databases set up like this.

Comment: *"You are not considering the problem I have, you invented a new one."* I do; table partitioning is what you want. A separate database for each year is a bad design.

Comment: What you can do is define synonyms for each database, instead of using 4-part naming in each query.  But I agree with @Larnu - change your design to use one archive database instead of a separate database for each year and partition the tables (if needed).

Comment: Context is everything guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the below steps:

1. Create a linked server pointing to older server
2. Create an Empty Database in the new server, corresponding to older database in the older server.
3. Create synonym for each object in the older database in the Empty database

Now, When you refer to synonyms in the empty database, it will appear as if the older database resides in the new server.

Comment: You don't need a blank/empty database to use synonyms.  Those synonyms can be created in the main database.

Comment: @Jeff, he wanted to see old database also being listed on the new server. So that is the reason, I suggested to create empty database with same name as old database and create synonyms there.